# Invalid arguments running parquet-tools jar

Tags: java, jar, parquet

I'm trying to print one column from a parquet file using parquet-tools.jar (https://github.com/Parquet/parquet-mr/tree/master/parquet-tools).
I'm using this command:

`java -jar parquet-tools-1.6.1-SNAPSHOT.jar dump -c COLUMNNAME someParquet.parquet`

But I get:

```
Invalid arguments: missing required arguments

usage: parquet-dump [option...] <input>
where option is one of:
    -c,--column <arg>  Dump only the given column, can be specified more than
                       once
    -d,--disable-data  Do not dump column data
       --debug         Enable debug output
    -h,--help          Show this help string
    -m,--disable-meta  Do not dump row group and page metadata
       --no-color      Disable color output even if supported
where <input> is the parquet file to print to stdout
```

Not sure where I'm getting the syntax wrong.

Comment: Maybe you want to use these scripts https://github.com/wesleypeck/parquet-tools/tree/master/src/main/scripts - that should give you the syntax as proposed by the help page

Comment: I think you get the syntax right. This seems to be a bug in the Apache CLI library or in the way how parquet-tools uses it.

Comment: I agree, seems like a problem with apache cli usage. try using `--column NAME`, `--column=NAME` etc.

Answer (score 5):

Option -c,--column   is thinking that you have specified multiple columns as arguments for "dump" commnad and ending up in eating all arguments. Hence you are seeing the missing requirement argument exception.

One workaround solution, i can suggest that  you need to add one additional option just after the -c option. This will make CLI parser to stop eating unexpected arguments for -c option.

With Below command(added --debug option), you should be able to execute the program:

```
java -jar parquet-tools-1.6.1-SNAPSHOT.jar dump -c COLUMNNAME --debug someParquet.parquet
```

You can try --no-color instead of --debug too.

Hope this helps.